# Subpartition inside partiton not showed in lsblk or /dev/

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk, lsblk

I installed archlinux inside my /dev/sdb4 and used the guided partition scheme. After install i can't mount /dev/sdb4 (ext4). The error was `VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`.

lsblk shows me:

```
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0 768,3G  0 part /
├─sdb3   8:19   0  62,7G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb4   8:20   0   100G  0 part
```

but fdisk -l:

```
Gerät       Boot Anfang      Ende  Sektoren Größe Kn Typ
/dev/sdb4p1 *      6144    421887    415744  203M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdb4p2      522240 209418239 208896000 99,6G 83 Linux
```

The installer created two subpartitions inside the partition. A partition table on /dev/sdb4

Now i try to mount those partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb4p1 /mnt
mount: /mnt: Spezialgerät /dev/sdb4p1 ist nicht vorhanden.
       dmesg(1) könnte nach einem fehlgeschlagenen mount-Systemaufruf
       weitere Informationen liefern.
```

i cant. Obviously `/dev/sdb4p1` doesn't exist. What should i do?

Comment: What's your goal? Are you trying to dual-boot Arch with your existing OS, or to run Arch in a virtual machine? Or just recover something from the subpartitions? If you need to recover files from within the subpartitions, it's doable, but setting up an dual-boot OS to boot from a subpartition would require a special snowflake initramfs configuration that would probably be too much trouble for it's worth. For dualbooting, I'd recommend tearing down the `sdb4` and reinstalling with a more conventional partition layout.

Comment: My goal was indeed setup dualboot. tolcoM mentioned, I just get rid of this "special" subpartition setup, and set it up the classic way (separate partition, not subpartition), once I realize what happened. Subpartition wasn't my goal, it was an accident (arch-install just did this)
The key point to mention here is: lsblk didn't show the "correct" layout of my partition table. I was unaware of this although I am a heavy linux user. I loose lot of time, and a takeaway could be, allways check with fdisk -l to be sure, or use another tool? Couldn't find any information to this in the lsblk docs.

Comment: I don't think there is a well-known MBR or GPT partition type that would indicate "this partition is sub-partitioned with another MBR/GPT partition table", so in that sense, sub-partitions are an error and tools like `lsblk` won't probe for it. It is a consequence of the kernel treating any block device as equal, so in the presence of layerable device-mapper technologies (LVM, software RAID, multipathing, encryption), it is not trivial to detect if a particular block device is a whole disk or not... so partitioning tools won't even try and instead just hope the user knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

I think I can relate to this question with mounting partitions inside a `.img` file.

If my thinking is true, then running `sudo losetup --partscan --show --find /dev/sdb4` should create a loop device (such as `/dev/loop23`).

This should also create `/dev/loop23p1` (partition 1), `/dev/loop23p2` (partition 2), and so on depending on your number of partitions in `/dev/sdb4`, each which you can mount with `sudo mount /dev/loop23p1 [MOUNT_POINT]`, etc.

Note that `/dev/loop23` is just an example. Use the one that is returned by `losetup` command.

---

### Explanation:

`losetup` is a command used for setting up and controlling loop devices.

In the command `sudo losetup --partscan --show --find /dev/sdb4`, we specify the following tags:

- `--partscan`: This scans for available partitions in the specified block device.
- `--show`: This is used to tell `losetup` to output the loop device's name it assigns.
- `--find`: This option tells `losetup` to find for an unused loop device and assign it.
- `/dev/sdb4`: This is the name of your block device / partition.

The beauty of `--partscan` option is that it automatically scans for all available partitions and also creates the sub-loop devices named as `[loop dev]p1`, `[loop dev]p2`, `[loop dev]p3`, and so on. You can mount each sub-loop device as if it were a whole partition.

---

### Cleanup

Once you've done with the mount, you will have to, as usual, run `sudo umount [MOUNT_POINT]` to unmount your mounted partition. Except that, we will also have to remove the loop device we created, using `sudo losetup -d [loop dev]` (substitute `[loop dev]` with the loop device's name that `losetup` returned earlier.

To confirm the loop device is deleted, you can simply run `losetup`.